# Error using Stable Diffusion: cannot import name 'is_modelcards_available' from 'diffusers.utils.import_utils'

Tags: python-import, huggingface, stable-diffusion

I'm new to Stable Diffusion; I've followed their instructions to install it https://huggingface.co/blog/stable_diffusion but when I run:

`from diffusers import StableDiffusionPipeline`

I get the error

`ImportError: cannot import name 'is_modelcards_available' from 'diffusers.utils.import_utils'`

I can't find any reference to this on the Internet, any ideas? Thanks!